# Problem with jquery hide(); after switchClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a `.menu` div and when I click that it opens a modal and the `.menu` is changes to `.menu-open`. This works correctly, but I would like to close my modal when I click `.menu-open`, yet nothing happens.

Can you help me please? What's wrong with the code? Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu").click(function() {
    $('.menu-modal').show();
    $(".menu").switchClass("menu", "menu-open");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-open").click(function() {
    $('.menu-modal').hide();
    $(".menu-open").switchClass("menu-open", "menu");
  });
});
```

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: `$(".menu-open").click` only applies to elements that exist *at the time the code runs* - which yours don't as you add the class later.  Use **event delegation**.  `$(document).on("click", ".menu-open", function...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: While not strictly "dynamically *created*" - see the link for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(function() {
  function openMenu(){
    $('.menu-modal').show();
    $(".menu").switchClass("menu", "menu-open");
    $(this).off("click");
    $(this).click(closeMenu);
  }

  function closeMenu(){
    $(".menu-modal").hide();
    $(".menu-open").switchClass("menu-open", "menu");
    $(this).off("click");
    $(this).click(openMenu);
  }

  $(".menu").click(openMenu);
});
```

Since you're changing the Class, it is not in the DOM any longer and the original callback will not be run. We will need to unbind that callback using `.off()` and assign the new action.

You could also do the following.

```
$(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".menu", function(){
    $('.menu-modal').show();
    $(".menu").switchClass("menu", "menu-open");
  }

  $("body").on("click", ".menu-open", function(){
    $(".menu-modal").hide();
    $(".menu-open").switchClass("menu-open", "menu");
  }
});
```

Using `.on()` will help delegate the callback to the selector.

See more:

- https://api.jquery.com/off/
- https://api.jquery.com/on/

The only caveat, **if the Modal is covering the element** that needs to be clicked, the click event will not be able to target that element.